# Check if app whitelisted from battery optimisation (doze mode)

Tags: android, whitelist, android-doze

How to check if my app already whitelisted from battery optimisation (doze mode) at its setting? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use the below code to see if a specific package is whitelisted for battery optimization:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean status = pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName);
Log.d("Optimization Status : "+status );
```

Reference : [PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(Package)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(java.lang.String))